# Linear transformation matrix to find trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm looking for a matrix that it's product with an $n\times n$ matrix that will return the trace of the matrix. Any ideas of how to build one?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I'm trying to find the dimension of the vector space of all the nXn matrices where the trace is 0.

Comment: If AB = a diagonal matrix D then $B = A^{-1}D$

Answer (score 1):

For any linear transformation $T$ from the space of size $n$ column vectors to size $m$ column vectors, we can always find an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ such that for every column vector $x$ (of size $n$), we have
$$
T(x) = Ax
$$
However, if we have a linear transformation from $n \times n$ matrices to $\Bbb R$, we **cannot** find a matrix $A$ such that for an $n \times n$ matrix $M$,
$$
T(x) = AM
$$
In order to build the matrix of a linear transformation on any space that does not consist explicitly of column vectors, we need to choose a **basis** of that space and find the matrix relative to that basis.

---

The easier way to answer your question, however, is to think of the linear transformation "trace" without finding its matrix with respect to *any* basis.  In particular,  note that trace is a map from $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ to $\Bbb R$.  $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is $n^2$ dimensional, and $\Bbb R$ is $1$-dimensional.

The map trace is onto, so the rank of the "trace" operation is $1$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the null-space of the trace operation is $n^2 - 1$.  Note that this null-space is precisely the set of matrices that has a trace of $0$.

Thus, the dimension of the space that you're looking for is $n^2 - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $V=M_n(\Bbb R)$ and $W=\{A\in V:\operatorname{tr}(A)=0\}$. If $A=(a_{ij})\in W$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$ and so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{a_{ii}}=0$. Without loss of generality assume that $a_{11}\neq 0$. Then $a_{11}=-a_{22}-\dotsm-a_{nn}$. Since $A=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n{a_{ij}E_{ij}}$, where $E_{ij}$ is the elementary matrix with $1$ at the $ij^\text{th}$-entry and all other entries are zero. Thus we have $A=\sum\limits_{i=2}^n{a_{ii}(E_{ii}-E_{11})}+\sum\limits_{i,j,i\neq j}{a_{ij}E_{ij}}$. Then show that the set $S=\{E_{ii}-E_{11}:2\le i\le n\}\cup\{E_{ij}:1\le i\neq j\le n\}$ is a basis for $W$ and hence $\dim W=n^2-1.$

Answer (score 0):

Trace is a non identically zero linear form $$\operatorname{tr}:\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$$
Therefore the kernel of trace is a hyperplane of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$ and has dimension $n^2-1$

Comment: A *non-zero* linear form, specifically.